# Amazon S3 PUT range header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently using the range header for GET request on Amazon S3 but I can't find an equivalent for PUT requests.

Do I have to upload the entire file again or can I specify where in the file I want to update? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Need to upload it again. S3 does not have a concept of either append and/or editing afile

However, if its a long file, you can do something called "Multipart Upload", and send several pieces of file, and merge it back at AWS:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html